# Kafka Connect - No converter present due to unexpected object type: java.lang.Double

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I have a Kafka Streams application, which does some calculations based on values from topic, sing sliding windows. I read, that the best practice for persisting the data would be to push the values to another topic, and use Kafka Connect to get data from topic and save it in the database.

I downloaded the confluent/kafka-connect image and extended it by installing mongodb-kafka-connector using the dockerfile.

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:7.0.3
COPY target/components/packages/mongodb-kafka-connect-mongodb-1.7.0.zip /tmp/mongodb-kafka-connect-mongodb-1.7.0.zip

RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt /tmp/mongodb-kafka-connect-mongodb-1.7.0.zip
```

I sent a request with config to the kafka connect:

```
 curl -X PUT http://localhost:8083/connectors/sink-mongodb-users/config -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d ' {
    "connector.class":"com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max":"1",
    "topics":"MOVINGAVG",
    "connection.uri":"mongodb://mongo:27017",
    "database":"Temperature",
    "collection":"MovingAverage",
    "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable":true,
    "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.DoubleConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable":true
    }'
```

The Kafka Streams app producing records:

```
StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();
        KStream<String, Double> kafkaStreams = streamsBuilder.stream(topic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Double()));
        Duration timeDifference = Duration.ofSeconds(30);

        KTable table = kafkaStreams.groupByKey()
                .windowedBy(SlidingWindows.ofTimeDifferenceWithNoGrace(timeDifference))
                .aggregate(
                        () -> generateTuple(logger), // initializer
                        (key, value, aggregate) -> tempAggregator(key, value,aggregate, logger))
                .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()))
                .mapValues((ValueMapper<AggregationClass, Object>) tuple2 -> tuple2.getAverage());
        table.toStream().peek((k,v) -> System.out.println("Value:" + v)).to(targetTopic, Produced.valueSerde(Serdes.Double()));
        KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(streamsBuilder.build(), properties);
        streams.cleanUp();
        streams.start();
```

The messages are being put to the topic, and mongo connector is reading them, however an exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Could not convert value `2.1474836E7` into a BsonDocument.

at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.converter.LazyBsonDocument.getUnwrapped(LazyBsonDocument.java:169)

at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.converter.LazyBsonDocument.containsKey(LazyBsonDocument.java:83)

at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.DocumentIdAdder.shouldAppend(DocumentIdAdder.java:68)

at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.DocumentIdAdder.lambda$process$0(DocumentIdAdder.java:51)

at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:183)

at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.DocumentIdAdder.process(DocumentIdAdder.java:49)

at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.MongoProcessedSinkRecordData.lambda$buildWriteModel$1(MongoProcessedSinkRecordData.java:90)

at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)

at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Collections.java:1085)

at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.MongoProcessedSinkRecordData.lambda$buildWriteModel$2(MongoProcessedSinkRecordData.java:90)

at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.MongoProcessedSinkRecordData.tryProcess(MongoProcessedSinkRecordData.java:105)

at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.MongoProcessedSinkRecordData.buildWriteModel(MongoProcessedSinkRecordData.java:85)

at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.MongoProcessedSinkRecordData.createWriteModel(MongoProcessedSinkRecordData.java:81)

at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.MongoProcessedSinkRecordData.<init>(MongoProcessedSinkRecordData.java:51)

at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.MongoSinkRecordProcessor.orderedGroupByTopicAndNamespace(MongoSinkRecordProcessor.java:45)

at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.StartedMongoSinkTask.put(StartedMongoSinkTask.java:75)

at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.MongoSinkTask.put(MongoSinkTask.java:90)

at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:601)

... 10 more

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: No converter present due to unexpected object type: java.lang.Double

at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.converter.SinkConverter.getRecordConverter(SinkConverter.java:92)

at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.converter.SinkConverter.lambda$convert$1(SinkConverter.java:60)

at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.converter.LazyBsonDocument.getUnwrapped(LazyBsonDocument.java:166)

... 27 more
```

Why such exception would be thrown?

Comment: You should try using JSONConverter instead. String nor Double converter have schemas, by the way, so those "enable" settings do nothing (this is only a property of the JSONConverter)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion!  Changing converter to JSONConverter left me this error:
`Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('@' (code 64)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')

 at [Source: (byte[])"@2�\(�"; line: 1, column: 2]`

Comment: You might have to set the schemas enable property to false since you only have numbers, but also, you might not be able to directly write numbers into mongo collection as there needs to be key-value pairs for documents.

Comment: Setting schema enable property didn't actually change anything. So I decided to create JSON serializer and deserializer using this [link](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/1.0/streams/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/examples/pageview/JsonPOJOSerializer.java), Which leaves me with error: `Unrecognized Type: [null]`

Comment: Hmm. That class is roughly the same as the [built in one](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/json/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/json/JsonSerializer.java#L30). But, like I said, Mongo most likely [wants KV pairs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kafka-connector/v1.7/sink-connector/fundamentals/write-strategies/), and a null record is not that. You would change the mapValues to return just `AggregationClass` as JSON like `{"average": 2.0}`, for example.

Comment: Something like this?
`.mapValues(agg -> createJSONString(agg))` where `createJSONString()` is returning a JSONObject?

Comment: Right, then change the Produced.valueSerde to use the JSONSerde

Comment: Using `Produced.valueSerde(Serdes.String()` made it work, thank you!

Comment: Cool. Feel free to show complete solution below as an answer